# How to get file path dynamically in production stage?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, django, python-3.x

I am doing an django application which is now running on aws ec2 instance, in that application i have one functionality for upload files to s3. While uploading s3 earlier i set folder path in settings.py from where i pick ups those files. But now on production it is difficult to go with this approach. For security reasons browser are now not allowing to get file path on file selection. Please any hint/solution would be great help.

Comment: what did you mean by this `While uploading s3 earlier i set folder path in settings.py from where i pick ups those files. But now on production it is difficult to go with this approach. For security reasons browser are now not allowing it`

Comment: Amazon S3 has an API that allows you to read or upload files. Have you explored creating an API wrapper from your django application to Amazon S3?

Comment: @zero will check that.

Comment: @ruddra I set folder path in settings.py file of django, and with this approach i can only pick up file from that folder. Because while uploading to s3 i have to get whole file path to read and write.